# Direct MySQL Query or Cached File - which is faster?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to determine if getting results directly from the mysql database, under a heavy load, is faster or slower than getting results from a cached file.  Which will be the fastest in any situation.

I have two sets of data which I'm using a cached file on.  I'm using PDO.

1. One displays a list of categories which returns - category letter, category name, and category number results. I'm pulling 400 categories per page.
2. Video thumbnails which returns - title, url, views, source, and duration.  I'm pulling about 140 thumbs w/ data per page.

I have the cache file set up to serialize the array results and save then to a file.  If the cached file time is still valid it will display the results from the cached file versus from the database.

I'm trying to determine if querying the database is better than accessing the cache file to display the results.  Tests I've done seem to indicate that getting the results from the file is faster than the database.  But, I'm not a guru by any stretch... so I wanted to see if anyone can help me with some feedback.

Thanks!

Comment: The entire point of a cache is to speed up load times by not having to process repetitive queries.

Comment: Even farster is to built the output once and flush to the browser with include(es). Which is a cache techinque also. Of course, this files can be renewed on a regular time basis.

Answer (score 1):

Faster than file based cache can be for example the memcached or redis server!

Comment: + 1 Indeed, memory cache is the best way of caching data otherwise available on high latency storage, like non-local mySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Cached file of course. That's the point of caching data.

Answer (score 0):

TIAS

The whole point of caching is to speed up the website particularly on database calls which are generally the slowest part of a website.

But more importantly is you could've run benchmarks on this much faster than typing up this question and waiting for a response. Install xdebug on your development box and download a parser to tell you where you are saving time and where your bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 0):

Caching to files is faster. You're on the right way!

If you are using just one unix server and have enough free memory, maybe the easiest and fastest method is to store the serialized data to files on in-memory /tmp -filesystem. So, forget memcached if possible. Also remember to give enough memory to mysql query cache if you don't have patience to implement caching everywhere. Home made caching is the lightest and thus the fastest way if made right.

Depending on your data, it might be better to just delete the cached file just before the data is changed instead of using expiration time. This way you know the data is good if the file exists.

And because you're interested of speed... I get much more power using basic mysql-functions instead of PDO or mysqli. And of course lighty instead of apache :)